# How to extract pigment from juice

Tags: extraction

Let's say I have carrot juice, standard kitchen and access to grocery store. How do I extract pigment from Orange juice? Sugars need to be separated out.

What's the fastest option? I thought about filtering, sedimentation, heating.

Comment: Do you have access to organic solvents?

Comment: Like what? I don't know this class.

Comment: Solvents immiscible with water suc has ethyl acetate or dichloromethane

Comment: @Waylander Since they have standard kitchen equipment: what about using oil to create two phases and separate water-soluble (sugars)  content?

Comment: Could do, but then you have a solution of the pigment in oil and it will not be straightforward getting it away from the oil.

Comment: Is coconut oil Ok? How to do oil extraction?

Comment: If your coconut oil does not mix with water then the beta-carotene which is the main pigment will go into the oil phase when you thoroughly mix the carrot juice and water. The sugars are water-soluble.